# Ruby Equivalent of Python Requests Library (HTTP Client)

Tags: ruby, http

There is a library in Python that I love called "Requests". Requests is a HTTP client build on urllib3. "[requests doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)".

I am looking for something similar in Ruby. Basically what I need is:

- Upload files support (multipart/form-data).
- Easy get/post.
- Cookies can be passed from a response object to a request object (build manually login script).
- Stable and Flexible.
- Sessions support (to not have to handle cookies manually if we don't have too).

I've looked at Typhoeus, but the code example in the home page doesn't work; they have moved code along and the `get` method is not longer directly accessible like that, so it's not starting well.  Curb seems nice and I like cURL, there is also rest-client, which seems popular, and em-http seems pretty fast according to benchmark. There is a also Patron and curb-fu, which I haven't have the time to try. And, of course, Net:HTTP. But, it doesn't seem to have a mainstream solution that everyone points to.

I think a lot of people have been in my situation and I wonder what they have choosen and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've eventually found this HTTPClient :
https://github.com/nahi/httpclient

I've started using it, it matches the features I wanted, and more over it's pretty fast according to some benchmark. It also support some advanced things like streaming or chunked response. It's shame though it's not famous in the ruby community. :)

Answer (score 11):

The author of the comparison is the author of `httpclient`, but from the looks of it the comparison is fair.

For a more narrative style with some explanation of the matrix, see http://www.slideshare.net/HiroshiNakamura/rubyhttp-clients-comparison from the same author.

The comparison comes out partly in favor of httpclient, which I can also recommend. Simple, featureful, compatible with all Ruby platforms and performant. Better cookie support than anything else out there, but the presentation mentions that cookies may leak from one (malevolent) site to another if you use the same client object. Don't know if this is still true.

Comment: Yeah, it's still the case for the cookie stuff. Fortunately, it's a big security hole, it's just that you can setup cookies for `.com.` domain name.

Comment: As long as you are aware of it, it probably is not a big problem. I *think* (don't trust me! verify!) that as long as you instantiate two different objects for two sites, you should be fine.

Comment: unfortunately httpclient is not actively maintained. I found [Excon](https://github.com/geemus/excon) is good

Comment: Latest release of https://github.com/nahi/httpclient was "Jun 8, 2014 - version 2.4.0". `httpclient` is actively maintained. It's just so close to perfection it doesn't need many updates. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

There is https://github.com/cyx/requests, which is exactly what the question is asking for, a port of the requests lib from python.

Answer (score 6):

The built-in [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) is the first place to look. It's simple and handles the basics nicely.

Typhoeus, which I've used several times for parallel processes, works nicely. [Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/frames/Typhoeus) and [the codebase](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) are available at Github.

```
irb(main):009:0> response = Typhoeus::Request.get("www.example.com")
=> #<Typhoeus::Response:0x007ffbcc067cf8 @code=302, @curl_return_code=0, @curl_error_message="No error", @status_message=nil, @http_version=nil, @headers="HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/\r\nServer: BigIP\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n", @body="", @time=0.035584, @requested_url=nil, @requested_http_method=nil, @start_time=nil, @start_transfer_time=0.035529, @app_connect_time=2.8e-05, @pretransfer_time=0.000429, @connect_time=2.8e-05, @name_lookup_time=2.8e-05, @request=:method => :get,
    :url => www.example.com, @effective_url="HTTP://www.example.com", @primary_ip="192.0.43.10", @redirect_count=0, @mock=false>
irb(main):010:0> puts response.headers
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

I use Net::HTTP occasionally too, but OpenURI and Typhoeus, with Hydra, have proven to be easy to use and integrate with my code.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [HTTParty](https://rubygems.org/gems/httparty/) gem?

Answer (score 2):

If you need cookies and form handling, [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) is the only way to go.

Comment: I think mechanize simulate a whole browser, nope?

Comment: I use httpclient a lot. It's a great library for when you want something lightweight. But it doesn't do everything on your list and mechanize does.

Comment: If you hadn't down-voted my answer I might be inclined to tell you.

Comment: I can't change my vote unless u make am edit. (Make a tiny one like a smiley, that's enough). I am curious. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to hear, that Typhoeus didn't work out for you. The reason is, that the README shows howto work with Typhoeus v0.5.0.rc which can be installed with

```
gem install typhoeus --pre
```

or

```
gem "typhoeus", git: "git://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus.git"
```

.
There is no session support for Typhoeus but other than that it could be a good fit. At least its stable as hell since it is build on top of libcurl.

File sending example:

```
Typhoeus.post("www.example.com/file", body: { file: File.open("testfile.txt","r") })
```

There is unfortunately no shortcut to deal with cookies, you have to set them manually:

```
Typhoeus.get("www.example.com/needs_cookie", headers: { Cookie: "PRIVATE" })
```

**TLDR**: I would choose Typhoeus for its speed and libcurl if you're willing to set things up yourself. Otherwise I would look into [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday) and use it with the Typhoeus adapter.

Edit: I've added installation instructions to the [README](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/commit/24990d1eb5371a2f49019c3d3381a4fba6766da4).

Edit: 0.5 is released.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be lacking recent answers. So am filling in the void.

Coming from python myself, and having loved requests library for what it does easily, I recently discovered a very nice Ruby equivalent in [rest_client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

It supports all the features mentioned in the question, and seems to be very nice from usability perspective - what requests library aimed to achieve.

Comment: Ended up using `http.rb`. It's okay.